# how to request a fields_for partial via ajax?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, nested-forms, formbuilder

i have a nested form model

```
<%= simple_form_for(@product, :html => { :multipart => true })  do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :name %>
 #... and some other

 <%= f.simple_fields_for :productgroups do |builder| %>
   <%= render 'form_productgroup', { :f => builder } %>
 <% end %>

<% end %>

## partial-level-1: form_productgroup
<%= f.input :extrapercentage %>
#... and some other

<%= f.simple_fields_for :productmaterials do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'form_productmaterial', { :f => builder } %>
<% end %>

## partial-level-2: form_productmaterial
<%= f.input :price %>
#... and some other
```

=> everything fine serverside, but i need to add records via ajax because each productgroup or productmaterial belongs to a specific type

now the question:

how to create a controller action which returns the new material form?

This code returns an error that f is not existing:

```
def new_productgroup
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @productgroup = Productgroup.new(:product_id => @product.id, :materialgroup_id => params[:materialgroup_id])
  render "form_productgroup", { :f => ???? }
end
```

please help me!

Comment: Controller does not create a new form, view does. In a controller action, you just need to render that view. Since you want to use AJAX, you just pass :remote => true to the form_for or simple_form_for method.